# How can I create a code that charges a 'penny' for every second that my code is ran? (Python)

Tags: python, datetime, spyder

I want to create a code that charges 'money' for every second that my program is ran. For example, if I am charging 1 cent for every second that the program is ran, and the program is ran for 10 seconds, I want a statement to be printed like "You have ran the program for 10 seconds, and will be charged 10 cents" at the end of my program.

I don't even know where to start on this, but so far, I've created a code that shows me how long my program has been ran for. The code looks like this:

```
from datetime import datetime
start_time = datetime.now()
#my code
end_time = datetime.now()
print("Duration:", end_time-start_time)
```

How can I go from here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're mostly there; just get the `total_seconds()` from the `timedelta` you got from subtracting the two `datetime`s.

```
elapsed = (end_time-start_time).total_seconds()
print(f"You have ran the program for {elapsed} seconds, and will be charged {elapsed} cents.")
```

Comment: thanks! is there a way that i can get rid of that decimal when im getting the cents charged? i want it to just say 3 cents, not 3.47283891 cents. i may do the same with the time, since its kinda strange to say '3.45212' seconds.

Comment: Round it: `{elapsed:.0f}` to round `elapsed` to 0 decimal places.